# Is there a better way of updating the tx hash?

Tags: reactjs, solidity, web3js, react-state-management

Following is a snippet of my code (which is working)

```js
....

let txhash = '';

class App extends Component {
  ....

  async componentDidMount() {
    .....
  }

  onSubmit = async(event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();

    this.setState({
      message: "Waiting for the transaction to be mined..."
    });

    await lottery.methods.enterLotteryContract().send({
      from: accounts[0],
      value: web3.utils.toWei(this.state.value, 'ether')
    }).on('transactionHash', function(hash) {
      txhash = hash
    });

    this.setState({
      message: "Congrats, the tx has been mined; your txhash  is " + txhash
    })
    console.log(txhash);
  });
}
```

More over here: https://github.com/DKSukhani/lottery-react/blob/master/src/App.js

Was wondering if there is a better way for me to get the `txhash` and then display it. I was hoping that I could make `txhash` as one of the state components rather than declaring it as an empty variable. Also I am using the call back function in only reassigning it to `txhash`.

Answer (score 0):

Can you ask your question a bit more clearly?  Your code makes sense and looks fine for some unknown purpose.  That purpose is exactly what I need to know though.

- When do you need the txHash, is it after every call of this function or are you trying to track something else.
- Why can't it be a state variable, you didn't include state in your snipped so I had to go look at the rest of your code and see no reason why not.  You use it within the snippet so it's clear you **can** use it to some degree.  I don't use React so maybe there's some render loop, listener issue, or other reason you can't use setState.

With that said, check out [this link](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-contract.html#id22) on the different events you can listen to with `on`, as I think you're listening to the wrong event or outputting the wrong text.  When you set the state's message to say that the tx was mined I don't believe it actually has been.

I would use `confirmation` and only display the message on the first fire of the event, then ignore the remaining 23.  The object returned alongside the confirmation number is described [here](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-contract.html#contract-events-return) and has a `transactionHash` variable you can use to both check that the transaction was confirmed and get the hash at the same time.  Now your event call is no longer as wasteful and you can use the same setState call for the message as for the txHash, or even skip storing the txHash at all (as long as you can still use setState asynchronously).